# adding to state with usestate not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to maintain a track of use inputs with react's use state.

for some reason this is quite difficult.

the function i'm using right now is,

```
  function handleClick(e) {

    setAnswers([...answers,  answer ]);
    // setTheArray([, newElement]);

setAnswer()
    setTime(true);
    setStage(Stage + 1);
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
    console.log(answers);
  }
```

the input section looks like this,

```
<div className=" items-center ">
            <label for="answer" className="sr-only font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg">
              Answer
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setAnswer(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              value={answer}
              name="answer"
              id="answer"
              className=" items-center shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              placeholder="Enter Here"
            />
          </div>
```

and the button

```
 <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none"
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
        >
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polygon points="16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76"></polygon>
        </svg>
        <span>Submit </span>
      </button>
```

Essentially I want to keep track of the user inputs over time - I could just create a class based component, but i'd rather just use functions if possible.

#### This is the entire component,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import { requireAuth } from "util/auth.js";
import Sidebar_Users from "components/dashboard/Sidebar/Sidebar_Users";
import MindVaultSection from "components/dashboard/MindVault/MindVaultSection";
import BottomNavigation from "../../components/dashboard/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation";

/*
  This page takes a measurement of someone's working memory,
  being how many digits they
  are able to remember in a set time period.

  To do this there needs to be:
  - Digits made randomly,
  - Timer,
  - Input for user answers based on the progress through the task,
  - Record of medication, or lack thereof

  Ideally doing 6 tests total - sending data at each point if possible, perhaps just as a total query at end though.

  User Flow

   - Initial Component
   - Component for remembering Text
   - Component for entering
   - Rest Component

  */

function makeid(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}

function ButtonBaseline(props) {
  const { time, Colour, handleClick, Stage, onSubmit } = props;
  if (time == false)
    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none"
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
        >
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polygon points="16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76"></polygon>
        </svg>
        <span>Get Started</span>
      </button>
    );
  else if (time == "input" && Stage < 6)
    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none"
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
        >
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polygon points="16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76"></polygon>
        </svg>
        <span>Next Step </span>
      </button>
    );
  else if (time == "input" && Stage == 6)
    return (
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none"
      >
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5"
        >
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polygon points="16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76"></polygon>
        </svg>
        <span>Submit </span>
      </button>
    );
  else
    return (
      <div className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none">
        Waiting!
      </div>
    );
}

function Baseline(props) {

  const [Stage, setStage] = useState(0); // walkthrough Status
  const [time, setTime] = useState(false); //timer off, on, or in input stage.
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  // RandomString generates a random string of length n
  var numbers = makeid(0 + 2 * Stage);
  //qSLeD9D0PlSE

  useEffect(() => {
    //this sets the time to wait, being 3 seconds
    if (time) {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        // do anything, this block runs after the timeout has "expired"
        // could even set state
        setTime("input");
        console.log("The timeout was called.");
      }, 3000); // timeout expires in 6000 ms
      // make sure to clear the timeout on component unmount to avoid memory loss issues

      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
      // this callback function runs only on component unmount, not re-renders
    }
  }, [time]);
  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setAnswer(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(e) {

    setAnswers([...answers,  answer ]);
    // setTheArray([, newElement]);

setAnswer()
    setTime(true);
    setStage(Stage + 1);
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
    console.log(answers);
  }
  let testInput;

  if (time == true) {
    testInput = (
      <>
        <div>Stage {Stage}</div>

        <div className="underline font-light    items-center justify-center">
          Hold the numbers in your head!
        </div>
        <div className="uppercase bg-white tracking-widest  text-center font-bold text-5xl shadow p-4 items-center">
          {numbers}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else if (time == "input") {
    testInput = (
      <>
        <div>Stage {Stage}</div>

        <div className="font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg">Enter Numbers</div>
        <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 items-center justify-center">
          <div className=" items-center ">
            <label for="answer" className="sr-only font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg">
              Answer
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              type="text"
              value={answer}
              name="answer"
              id="answer"
              className=" items-center shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              placeholder="Enter Here"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else if (time == false) {
    testInput = (
      <>
        <p className="text-lg leading-7 text-gray-500 mb-5">
          You are about to do a small short term memory test. A few letters will
          flash on your computer monitor for 3 seconds. Your job is to write
          down as many letters as you can remember
        </p>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar_Users dashboard={"Progress Map"}>
        <div className="py-8 min-h-full container mx-auto   ">
          <div className="mt-2 mb-8 text-3xl leading-8 font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10">
            Working Memory Test
          </div>
          {testInput}

          <ButtonBaseline
            time={time}
            Stage={Stage}
            handleClick={handleClick}
            // onSubmit={onSubmit}
          />
        </div>
      </Sidebar_Users>
    </>
  );
}

export default Baseline;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Could you further elaborate on what you mean by "keep track of user inputs over time"? Generally, your useState hook keeps track of the input value but, what do you mean by over time?

Comment: So, on each button click a new input is shown essentially (the user see's a bunch of numbers, then they have to input those numbers again, for 6 stages). So, those inputs I want to have in a datastore that i then send off to a database. Does that make sense?

Comment: i.e., stage 1:asda. then stage 2:adpwdw

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: I don't see what is the point of `Stage` state. It seems that keep tracking `answers` length.

Comment: besides, your `console.log(answers)` will always display an outdated state given setState being async

Comment: Oh yeah it is! yeah, i wondered why that was happening. Is there a better way to manage this? Perhaps a different button change function?

Comment: I'll add to my answer how to manage stages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would keep track of all your answers. Since you don't have all your code dealing with stages I can't make this answer more specific
but, if this is not enough letme know where to elaborate.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (answers.length === 6) {
      //here you would fire your submit to server
      setIsSubmit(true);
    }
  }, [answers]);

  function handleClick(e) {
    if (!isSubmit) setAnswers([...answers, answer]);
  }

  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setAnswer(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={answer} onChange={handleOnChange} />
      <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Submit</button>
      <ul>
        {answers.map((item) => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {isSubmit ? "Has Submitted" : "Has not Submitted"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit busy-kalam-f6tt9]

Update: Added some stage logic

Comment: Made some changes to show all my component logic @Nicholas_Jones